# Developing MS Outlook Add in .NET

Tags: plugins, outlook, vsto

I am working on a legacy application in which we have add in for Outlook and other MS office applications coded in C++, and COM technologies. The work of the plugin is to save files/attachments to our archive servers. We are going to develop a new version of this add in using .NET.

Can you help me with guidance that how the Add in can be developed in .NET? The add in is for MS Office desktop version and not for web version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VSTO - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019

It is still very much COM based, but VSTO run-time hides that pretty well.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I will try this. Are there any other ways also of coding office plugins using .NET? Asking this for my knowledge.

Comment: Sure, you can do straight COM without VSTO - implement IDTExtensibility2, IRibbonExtensibility, etc. interfaces explicitly in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying VSTO. It hides all complexities of COM and provides easy interface to write the plugin.